# sparse least square regression

Tags: python, scipy, regression, sparse-matrix

I am trying to fit a linear regression `Ax = b` where `A` is a sparse matrix and `b` a sparse vector. I tried `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr` but apparently `b` needs to be a numpy (dense) array. Indeed if i run

```
A = [list(range(0,10)) for i in range(0,15)]
A = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(A)
b = list(range(0,15))
b = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(b)
scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr(A,b)
```

I end up with:

> AttributeError: squeeze not found

While

```
scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr(A,b.toarray())
```

seems to work.

Unfortunately, in my case b is a 1,5 billion x 1 vector and I simply can't use a dense array. Does anybody know a workaround or other libraries for running linear regression with sparse matrix and vector?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the documentation specifically asks for `numpy` array. However, given the scale of your problem, maybe its easier to use the closed-form solution of Linear Least Squares?

Given that you want to solve Ax = b, you can cast the normal equations and solve those instead. In other words, you'd solve `min ||Ax-b||`.

The closed form solution would be `x = (A.T*A)^{-1} * A.T *b`.
Of course, this closed form solution comes with its own requirements (specifically, on the rank of the matrix A).

You can solve for `x` using `spsolve` or if that's too expensive, then using an iterative solver (like Conjugate Gradients) to get an inexact solution.

The code would be:

```
A = scipy.sparse.rand(1500,1000,0.5) #Create a random instance
b = scipy.sparse.rand(1500,1,0.5)
x = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A.T*A,A.T*b)
x_lsqr = scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr(A,b.toarray()) #Just for comparison
print scipy.linalg.norm(x_lsqr[0]-x)
```

which on a few random instances, consistently gave me values less than `1E-7`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Indeed, I might need something iterative since terminal killed the process after a while.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently billions of observations is too much for my machine. I ended up:

1. Changing algorithm to Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD): faster with many obs
2. Removing completely sparse examples (i.e. features and label equal to zero)

Indeed, the update rule of SGD with least square loss function is always zero for obs in 2. This reduced observations from billions to millions which turned out to be feasible under SGD on my machine.