# Sparse partial least square regression in python

Tags: python, pls

I know there is a library for sparse PLS (developed by Chun and Keles 2010; DOI: 10.1111/j.1467-9868.2009.00723.x) in R, is there a library for SPLS in Python so I can readily use? 
BTW, SPLS is different from "sparse least square regression". Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sparse least square regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895814/sparse-least-square-regression)

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy They're different.

Comment: I hope you found solution already. Just in case you can use rpy2 to access R functions in Python. This worked out for me. The example is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454085/accessing-a-r-user-defined-function-in-python

Comment: @IngaKuznetsova Thanks for the info. I was about to use R, but I haven't had time to explore it due to a whole load of other important stuffs. So I appreciate your information and I will explore this function in near future.